# BizTalk outbound wcf requests

Tags: c#, wcf, biztalk

I'm using BizTalk 2010 and i'm trying to invoke a wcf service with many concurrent messages.

My question is: How can I control the quantity of the outbound messages sent by BizTalk enging to a WCF endpoint ?

I want to **increase** that number. When I open the administration console, I see a large number of messages with "Active" status, and the quantity of them decreases by 4-5 each second. Unfortunately that's not enough, and I want BizTalk to send about 20 per second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you already load-tested your WCF Service, and that it is capable of handling the load you require of it? The tool SoapUI can help you with this kind of testing, as it has a great Load Test feature.

The BizTalk sympton you describe, can be caused by [Outbound Host Throtling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578302.aspx). You can monitor this using the Host Throttling Performance Counters with PerfMon. You should focus on the "Message delivery throttling state" and "Message publishing throttling state" counters.

Also, how many hosts are you using in this scenario? It is a best practice to use separate hosts for sending, receiving, processing, and tracking functionality.

Finally, when working with HTTP based adapters (including the WCF-based ones), you should look at the [maxConnections parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee377083.aspx) in your BizTalk config file and tweak it to your needs.